# Remove portion of a remote file using SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp

I would like to remove a portion of a file using the SFTP protocol. Example:

`This is a sample text.` --> `This is a text.`

The standard protocol [write operation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-6.4) takes an offset and a string of data as inputs. However, the interface does not specify a file length to possibly remove characters from the file. That way the file can only ever grow in size. In the above example, if I attempted to update the file using write, the resulting output would be:

`This is a text.e text.`

What is the proper way of removing characters in SFTP? Is there perhaps a terminating character which is used to signal the end of a file when using write? Or do I have to just delete the entire file and re-upload a new one?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a part of a file contents. Not even from a local file, let only from a remote file over SFTP.

You have to overwrite the file – or at least whole part of the file starting with the first changed byte. And then truncate the file, in case the new contents is shorter than the original.

You can use `copy-data` SFTP extension to copy data within the file itself to avoid need to reupload the existing contents. If your SFTP server supports the extension. In OpenSSH, it's supported only in very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0).